# how to when variable is empty put this static html code in php

Tags: php, html

Hoping all will be fine...i want to do something like i have an php image uploader here is the link to uploader : http://alitechn.w08.wh-2.com/undo_testing/uploader/upload.php

so when someone open the link so the image shows blank i want to add some image in static html but normally when someone upload image so then that new image got replace the static image..!

here is the upload.php file full code:

```
<?php
    $fulltarget = '';

@$submit=$_POST['sub'];
if(isset($submit))
{
$name=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['img']['type'];

$size=($_FILES['img']['size'])/1024;

$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
if (($ext == "gif")
|| ($ext == "jpeg")
|| ($ext == "jpg")
|| ($ext =="png")
&& ($size > 30))
{


############################## File Renaming ###################################################

$newname=uniqid();
//$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
$fullname=$newname.".".$ext;
$target="pics/";

$fulltarget="http://alitechn.w08.wh-2.com/undo_testing/uploader/{$target}{$fullname}";
if($should_display_static){
$fulltarget="http://www.ipic-uk.com/images/homepage/upload_your_photo.png";


}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fulltarget))
{
echo "Success";
}
else
{
echo "Failed";
}
############################## File Renaming end ###################################################
}
else{
echo "not successful";
}
}
?>
    <div>
 <div id="a1">
 <form name="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="upload" style="width: 157px; height: 57px">  
  <input type="file" class="dark-button" name="img" style="width: 88px; height: 29px" /></div>
 <input type="submit" class="auto-style1" value="Store" style="width: 149px; height: 36px" /> 
<style type="text/css">
.styled-button-12 {
background:#5B74A8;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#5B74A8),color-stop(100%,#5B74A8));
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background:linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5B74A8',endColorstr='#5B74A8',GradientType=0);
padding:2px 6px;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Helvetica',sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
border-radius:0;
-moz-border-radius:0;
-webkit-border-radius:0;
border:1px solid #1A356E
}
.auto-style1 {
background: #5B74A8;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#5B74A8),color-stop(100%,#5B74A8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#5B74A8 0%,#5B74A8 100%);
background: #5B74A8;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5B74A8',endColorstr='#5B74A8',GradientType=0);
padding: 2px 6px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border: 1px solid #1A356E;
margin-left: 162;
}
</style>
</form>
</div>
<div id="a2">

<?php echo "

<html>
<head>
<title>Aviary Photo Editer</title>
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js'></script>
<!-- Instantiate Feather -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
apiKey: 'ceegvx4siylhayrr',
apiVersion: 3,
theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
tools: 'enhance,frames,crop,orientation,brightness,saturation,sharpness,draw,redeye,blemish,effects,stickers,resize,focus,contrast,warmth,colorsplash,text,whiten',
appendTo: '',
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
    var object = document.getElementsByName('cardlink');
    object.item(0).value=newURL;
    input.value= newURL;    

},
onError: function(errorObj) {
    alert(errorObj.message);
}
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
featherEditor.launch({
    image: id,
    url: src
 });
return false;
}
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='".$fulltarget."' width='300px' height='400px'/>

<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick=\"return launchEditor('image1','".$fulltarget."');\" /></p>";



?>

<div onSave="function(imageID, newURL);">
<form action="contact-form/index.php" method="post">
<div><label for="cardlink">Card Image Link:<input type="text" name="cardlink" id="cardlink" style="width: 323px; height: 25px" /></label></div>

                    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()"  class="dark-button add-to-cart">Submit</a>



                </input>    </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $fulltarget to be the absolute path to the image you want to display. Then, whenever you determine you want the static image to display, change $fulltarget to point to the static image.

```
$fulltarget="http://alitechn.w08.wh-2.com/undo_testing/uploader/{$target}{$fullname}";
```

then check if you want to display a static image (You dont specify the criteria)

```
if($should_display_static)[
    $fulltarget="http://path/to/static/image.jpg";
}
```

then obviously change your img code to:

```
<img id='image1' src='".$fulltarget."' width='300px' height='400px'/>
```

Comment: you never define the value of "should_declare_static" - this is up to your implementation, when do you want to display a static image rather than the user uploaded one

Comment: i want to show the static when someone didn't upload the image yet.. so what to do please..!

Comment: change should_display_static to !isset($_POST['sub'])

Comment: friend now getting following error : `Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/site/html_purple/pics/523dfdb704eb9.png): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\html_purple\upload.php on line 35

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpC6D3.tmp' to 'http://localhost/site/html_purple/pics/523dfdb704eb9.png' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\html_purple\upload.php on line 35`

Comment: change if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fulltarget)) to if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$target$fullname))